# Moving to Wordpress Premium versus a hosting provider

Tags: plugins, installation

My blog is now over a year old, and I've been considering moving my blog from Wordpress.com for a while.  My main reason for this is that I now how enough visitors that I believe I'd rather take the advertising revenue myself.  As I understand it, I can move this to a separate hosting provider, or simply upgrade to the WordPress "Premium" service.

I've seen a few questions regarding similar topics; but my questions are (I believe) slightly more specific.  First, these are some assumptions that I've made from the research I've done so far (are they all correct?):

1. WordPress Premium protects any Google ranking I may have.
2. I can add my own advertising plug-ins to Wordpress, but am restricted in their type (http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/what-are-the-best-ad-management-plugins-and-solutions-for-wordpress/).
3. That a Wordpress hosted site will require no more maintenance that I currently do on my Wordpress.com site; also, that it will require no work from me to upgrade.
4. I will be able to maintain and edit my blog in exactly the same way as I currently do.
5. That I am restricted to using my current domain name.

The things I don't know:

1. Do I have enough visitors to cover the cost of doing this (currently 500/month)?
2. What I am restricted from doing if I do go with Wordpress.org?
3. If I make the decision to go one way or the other, how difficult is that decision to reverse?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have enough visitors to cover the cost of doing this (currently 500/month)?

I have two hands, is it enough to earn a living? Well, it depends on what and where I am doing a lot.

Visitors do not magically make money appear. Advertisement is part of the process and it depends on a lot of things how well advertisement works in specific niche and how much money it makes on average per visit.

> What I am restricted from doing if I do go with Wordpress.org?

You can do absolutely anything, as long as it complies with Terms of Service of your hosting provider, laws of hosting provider's country, and laws of your country.

> If I make the decision to go one way or the other, how difficult is that decision to reverse?

The basic import/export of posts is not complicated, but if you use theme/plugins which aren't available on WordPress com obviously you would lose those parts going back to it.